# Assets Uploads Failing

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, error, php-errors, uploads

```
EE 2.5.5, Assets 2.1.3
```

I'm having an issue in the CP uploading images. My EE install uses the Focus Lab config system if that makes a difference.

When I try to do an upload via the Assets Module view (file manager) I get an error message:

```
Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings.
```

When looking at the request (?folder=2&ACT=39...) I get this error in the Chrome Inspector preview:
    A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: 4096

Message: Argument 1 passed to Assets_base_source::update_file_info() must be an instance of Assets_base_file, boolean given, called in /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/iso100/Sites/gde/third_party/assets/sources/base_source.php on line 642 and defined

Filename: sources/base_source.php

Line Number: 672

Fatal error: Call to a member function kind() on a non-object in /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/iso100/Sites/gde/third_party/assets/sources/base_source.php on line 681
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Ian, I haven't see this one before.  Is Super Admin and FTP access to this site available?  I think it'd probably be a lot faster if we just logged in and hade a look. Thank you!

Comment: Right now this site is in development and is only local to my machine. I could give Beanstalk access but that's a lot of work on your end to install and test.

Is there any other way to work though this or do I need to get the site in a public location?

Comment: Ian, let me see if Andris has any ideas on this before you go moving it; we may need access, but let's make sure before putting that work in.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across this issue too and it turns out while the EE filemanager doesn't mind a missing trailing slash on the server path, Assets does.

Make sure your upload directory server path *has* a trailing slash.

Resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Are we talking about the "server path" within IIS or within the ExpressionEngine Install?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my server path was incorrect in my config.master.php configuration. Sorry to burn your time on this but I just resolved the issue.

I tested uploading using Assets and it works perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know what was going on.  Unusual error output for that problem, but very glad you found it. Thank you Ian!